# Where is the Proper place to ask Job Questions on SO

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Considering an internal offer to change focus from Java to Groovy.  Would this be a good move?

Where would I ask a question like that?

Comment: I doubt that such an open-ended question is going to be a fit for *any* SE site.

Answer (score 10):

There is no good place on the Stack Exchange network for this kind of question - it is much too specific to a single person (so will not be of use to others, which is something that is desirable in a question).

It is also very open-ended - this is also not wanted.

There is a place to ask workplace related questions, though - [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), though this would be off-topic there as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of the chat rooms in [chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). There are likely to be many people with advice to offer.

I don't see any Groovy rooms, but there are plenty for Java. Just stay away from:
*Java Sucks - Suffocating from the stench of a thousand cow farts*... Their opinion is likely to be biased.

Comment: Can't imagine why they'd be biased.